# How to force Finder to refresh external drive? OS X

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, finder, osx-mavericks

I use an external hard drive for Time Machine backups. Recently, I moved it to a USB hub (so that I don't have as many cables to deal with). This has slowed down the speed which I can read/write to the disk. Time Machine can write to the disk just fine, but the read speeds are slow enough that it doesn't update the files (when viewed in Finder or in Time Machine). Instead, it just shows the state the drive was in when I first injected it. I don't know where these caches are stored, but I would like to turn them off.

Is there some way to force OS X not to cache external hard drives? I want it to read directly from the disk every time.

**EDIT:** The problem appears to lie with Finder simply not refreshing. I have fixed it with an AppleScript Service that updates the files, but a more elegant solution would be nice.

```
tell application "Finder"
  tell front window
    update every item with necessity
  end tell
end tell
```

[Source](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2009091413423819)

How can I make Finder refresh automatically when viewing an external drive?